# float depending on number of lines

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to achieve the following:
I have 2 elements.
If the screen is large enough, I want the second to float on the right:

```
--------el1--------               --------el2--------|
```

but not if the screen is too small:

```
--------el1--------             |
--------el2--------             |
```

I've tried to use `.container::first-line .el2{float: right;}` with some html like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="el1"></div>
  <div class="el2"></div>
</div>
```

and `.el1, .el2{display: inline-block;}`
. It fails. Interestingly if you look at it in the dev tools (on Chrome), the float property appears as active when it is excepted to, but the display ignores it.

http://jsfiddle.net/c9f2hf9z/1/

Any clue?

Comment: you cannot define a rule like `.container::first-line .el2` since an element can't be a child of a `::first-line` psuedoclass. see http://jsfiddle.net/xj98t1s9/

Comment: interesting and disappointing! Thanks!

Comment: Ok. In my case, I don't know when the elements will be displayed in two lines since their width depend of the content inside that can vary. So I cannot change the css rule according to the container's width, which you are using in your example.

Comment: so basically the blue elements (with unknown width) should stay in a single row until there's enough room for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` position: http://jsfiddle.net/xj98t1s9/2/

**CSS**

```
.container { 
    border: solid 1px black; 

    /* enable flexbox on container */
    display: flex;

    /* wrap the elements contained */
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    /* add a space between elements so they are aligned with the edges */
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>should be left</div>
    <div>should be right</div>
</div>
```

The direct children elements of `.container` will be aligned in a single row until there's enough room for them (try to stretch the *result* panel on jsfiddle). Also note that the classnames are not really necessary for this example, so you could simplify the markup.

Be aware of the [different support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (and syntax) across browser of flexbox module. A good tutorial on the subject can be found on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I'd also suggest playing with [FlexyBoxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) to better know Flex